# Custom attribute values Not showing while compare the product in magento2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes, compare

I have issue in **not showing Custom attribute values** in while **compare the products**

I have added some custom attribute and Set **Yes** to **Comparable on Storefront** in Admin side. After check Compare Products, Custom Attributes are Showing fine, But value show **N/A** ,  But All custom attribute value showed in **Product Details tab** in product details page. Only not viewing compare Product.

Reference:

[image]

Suggest me What is the problem and How to resolve this problem.

Comment: have you entered any text from backend?

Comment: @chirag  No, I have not entered any text in backend.

Comment: @chirag see my partial answer, now its worked , but  i need to know why this issue occur.

Comment: May be your attribute value is not store in database!

Comment: @chirag But, That custom attribute value viewed in Product details page in details  tab.

Comment: have you reindex after importing?

Comment: @chirag, Yes I have reindex, clear cache, and restart the mysql ,but Not view the custom attribute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have **partially fixed** my issue,

After I **Re-import** the product using csv file its fixed. But I need to Know Why this issue occur.